# AngularJS Philips Hue Project

Tags: javascript, api, angularjs, philips-hue

I started working on a little AngularJS - Philips Hue project and I'm kinda stuck...

I'm fairly new to AngularJS... but here goes.

What I want to do is to list the lamps I have, the status of the lamps and a toggler to switch them.

I decided to build a factory (based on this article: http://davidsalter.com/2013/08/16/using-angular-dot-js-factories-to-get-remote-data/) for the data getting/putting:

```
app.factory('lampsFactory', function($http) {
  return {
      getLamps: function(callback) {
          $http.get('http://172.16.0.2/api/newdeveloper/lights').success(callback);
      },
      getLampState: function(callback, lampID) {
          $http.get('http://172.16.0.2/api/newdeveloper/lights/'+ lampID).success(callback);
      }
  };
});
```

The getLamps function works as it should but I don't know how to get lamp data based on an id.
I tried to add an extra paremeter but that did not work.

Can you please help me and push me in the right direction?

I also have a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ySa0PVBahM7sxU4lasgP

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on this statement: `but that did not work`? You're not receiving the ID at the API access point? If that's the case, did you make sure the AJAX request is correctly passing the ID?

Comment: Ive changed my code so 
`getLampState: function(callback, lampID) {
          $http.get('http://172.16.0.2/api/newdeveloper/lights/'+ lampID).success(callback);
      }`

and my controller function to:
`$scope.getLampState = function(taskId){
    lampsFactory.getLampState(function(results) {
      console.log(results.state.on);
      return results.state.on;
  },taskId);
  };`

and it works! The only thing that does not work is the ng-repeat code:
`<td>{{getLampState($index + 1)}</td>`
It will keep repeating the getLampState function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've change the code to:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, lampsFactory) {

  lampsFactory.getLamps(function(results) {
      $scope.lamps = results;
  });

  $scope.getLampState = function(lampID){
    lampsFactory.getLampState(function(results) {
      console.log(results.state.on);
      return results.state.on;
  },lampID);
  };


});

app.factory('lampsFactory', function($http) {
  return {
      getLamps: function(callback) {
          $http.get('http://172.16.0.2/api/newdeveloper/lights').success(callback);
      },
      getLampState: function(callback, lampID) {
          $http.get('http://172.16.0.2/api/newdeveloper/lights/'+ lampID).success(callback);
      }
  };
});
```

and it works! Thanks!